# Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GUI stop but no command terminal)

Tags: command-line, sudo

I am new to Ubuntu Linux. I was trying to disable the GUI with one of the following commands_

sudo telinit 3
(OR)
sudo systemctl stop lightdm.

After typing one of these commands, the GUI stopped but there was no terminal display and cannot type any command. Only show the blink of underscore "_".
Please help me how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By default Ubuntu 16.04LTS has multiple virtual consoles (VCs) and the graphical user interface would normally run on VC7.

Try switching with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or try with one of the other function keys (<kbd>F2</kbd>..<kbd>F6</kbd>).